# Word length error in TextArea

Tags: jquery

I am trying to calculate how many words has the user typed in a text area

```
$("#word_count").on('keyup', function() {        
         var text = $(this).val;
         word_c = $.trim(text).split(' ').length;
$('#display_count').text(word_c);
});
```

However I am always getting wrong results. What am I missing?

http://jsfiddle.net/drxgw/

Comment: Multiple contiguous spaces? Try `.split(/\s+/)` - http://jsfiddle.net/drxgw/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems:

1. you were trying to use the `val` property of the jQuery object, instead of the `val()` method (the parentheses are not optional), and
2. you were declaring a global variable in the following line, corrected this gives:

   ```
   $("#word_count").on('keyup', function () {
       var text = $(this).val(),
           word_c = $.trim(text).split(' ').length;
       $('#display_count').text(word_c);
   });
   ```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/drxgw/2/).

Also, there's the problem of multiple white-space characters in your code leading to erroneous results (in the above demo type 'one[space][space][space]two' and the count will be 4); to correct that:

```
$("#word_count").on('keyup', function () {
    var text = $(this).val(),
        word_c = $.trim(text).split(/\s+/).length;
    $('#display_count').text(word_c);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/drxgw/4/).

To allow for word limitation:

```
$("#word_count").on('keydown', function (e) {
    var text = $(this).val(),
        words = $.trim(text).split(/\s+/),
        word_c = words.length;
    $('#display_count').text(word_c);
    return word_c < 21 || e.which == 8;
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/drxgw/6/).

References:

- [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).
- [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

Comment: thanks that works. How can I limit the total count to 20 words and not more than that?

Comment: what does e.which == 8 do?

Comment: That allows the back-space to occur (so if the `textarea` prevents further keystrokes being added it *won't* prevent the user deleting some of the content).

Comment: awesome! I am waiting for you to answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18878199/better-way-to-restrict-characters-in-textbox  :)

Answer (score 2):

change this line of code!

```
var text = $(this).val();
```

thanks to mr. Thomas, this is what you need

```
$("#word_count").on('keyup', function () {
    var text = $(this).val(),
        word_c = $.trim(text).split(/\s+/).length;
    $('#display_count').text(word_c);
});
```

for your comment to limitation, you can do this

```
$("#word_count").on('keydown', function () {
    var text = $(this).val(),
    word_c = $.trim(text).split(/\s+/).length;
    $('#display_count').text(word_c);
    if(word_c > 19)
       return false;
});
```

[Demo JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drxgw/5/)

Comment: Also need to account for multiple whitespace blocks.

Comment: Silly of me. Any idea if I have to limit the total words to only 20, how will I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#word_count").on('keyup', function() {        
         var text = $(this).val();
         word_c = $.trim(text).split(' ').length;
$('#display_count').text(word_c);
});
```

You were missing brackets on the $(this).val

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#word_count").on('keyup', function() {        
         var text = $(this).val();
         word_c = $.trim(text).split(/[ ]+/).length;
$('#display_count').text(word_c);
});
```

It also considers words separated by more than one whitespace. Split accepts regex.